# Embed a menu in a panel with wxWidgets or Win32

Tags: menu, wxwidgets, win32gui

I need to create a control that has the same behavior of a menu but is embedded in a panel and always kept open. It should look exactly like a context menu, but embedded in a panel and not floating.
I tried to do it in several different ways in wxWidgets, but a wxMenu cannot be added to a window with the exception of the wxMenuBar or with a popup menu.
Is anybody aware of a way to do it?
If not possible with wxWidgets, also using directly Win32 could be a choice.

Answer (score 0):

You could fake it!  Something along these lines:

- Create a small throw-away program that shows the menu you want
- Screen capture the menu
- Draw the menu picture on your panel in the real application
- Handle mouse clicks on the panel, and check the mouse co-ordinates to see which menu item was clicked, if any, and call the required item handler.